# Numpy: find indicies conditioned on values in two different arrays (coming from R)

Tags: python, arrays, r, numpy

I have a volume represented by a 3D ndarray, `X`, with values between, say, 0 and 255, and I have another 3D ndarray, `Y`, that is an arbitrary mask of the first array, with values of either 0 or 1.

I want to find the indicies of a random sample of 50 voxels that is both greater than zero in X, the 'image', and equal to 1 in Y, the 'mask'.

My experience is with R, where the following would work:

```
idx <- sample(which(X>0 & Y==1), 50)
```

Maybe the advantage in R is that I can index 3D arrays linearly, because just using a single index in numpy gives me a 2D matrix, for example.

I guess it probably involves `numpy.random.choice`, but it doesn't seem like I can use that conditionally, let alone conditioned on two different arrays. Is there another approach I should be using instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way -

```
N = 50 # number of samples needed (50 for your actual case)

# Get mask based on conditionals
mask = (X>0) & (Y==1)

# Get corresponding linear indices (easier to random sample in next step)
idx = np.flatnonzero(mask)

# Get random sample
rand_idx = np.random.choice(idx, N)

# Format into three columnar output (each col for each dim/axis)
out = np.c_[np.unravel_index(rand_idx, X.shape)]
```

If you need random sample without replacement, use `np.random.choice()` with optional arg `replace=False`.

Sample run -

```
In [34]: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: X = np.random.randint(0,4,(2,3,4))
    ...: Y = np.random.randint(0,2,(2,3,4))

In [35]: N = 5 # number of samples needed (50 for your actual case)
    ...: mask = (X>0) & (Y==1)
    ...: idx = np.flatnonzero(mask)
    ...: rand_idx = np.random.choice(idx, N)
    ...: out = np.c_[np.unravel_index(rand_idx, X.shape)]

In [37]: mask
Out[37]: 
array([[[False,  True,  True, False],
        [ True, False,  True, False],
        [ True, False,  True,  True]],

       [[False,  True,  True, False],
        [False, False, False,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True]]], dtype=bool)

In [38]: out
Out[38]: 
array([[1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 2],
       [1, 1, 3],
       [1, 1, 3]])
```

Correlate the output `out` against the places of `True` values in `mask` for a quick verification.

---

If you don't want to flatten for getting the linear indices and directly get the indices per dim/axis, we can do it like so -

```
i0,i1,i2 = np.where(mask)
rand_idx = np.random.choice(len(i0), N)
out = np.c_[i0,i1,i2][rand_idx]
```

For performance, index first and then concatenate with `np.c_` at the last step -

```
out = np.c_[i0[rand_idx], i1[rand_idx], i2[rand_idx]]
```

Comment: Thanks. btw, in your answer, what do the `In [34]:` line indicates? Is this some prompt feature of your environment? Mine simply has the >>>

Comment: @ElijahRockers Yeah I am on IPython console.